# Co-occurrences of words in a sentence in a PDF with R (tm package?)

Tags: r

So, my goal was to use R to code something that could scrub PDFs and pull when things are mentioned together-- for example whenever vasopressin and anterior hypothalamus are mentioned together in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/403c/fd873feb7055c9140b7abfa4584fa7ee1c7f.pdf or something like that. Most text analysis tutorials I have found generally get rid of punctuation and all that before text analysis, so it would be impossible to check when things get mentioned in the same sentence. Is this a possible thing to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Split your text on periods `.` first, then remove the punctuation on each sentence-block.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to say more in detail and give real example data, but in principle this is very doable. Here's an example that I hope you find helpful:

```
# here are some 'documents' -- just text strings
doc1 <- "hello. apple horse."
doc2 <- "hello. banana legislature"
doc3 <- "hello, apple banana. horse legislature"

# store them in a list...
list_of_docs <- list(doc1, doc2, doc3)

# ...so we can apply a custom function to this list
lapply(list_of_docs, function(d) {

  # split each document on the '.' character 
  # (fixed=T means interprest this as plain text, not regex)
  phrases_in_d <- unlist(strsplit(d, '.', fixed=T))

  # now here's a regex pattern to search for:
  #   apple followed by anything followed by banana, 
  #     OR 
  #   banana followed by anything followed by apple
  search_regex <- 'apple.*banana|banana.*apple'

  # grepl() returns a logical vector (TRUE or FALSE) to say if there's a match
  # for 'search regex' among 'phrases in document d'
  # any() returns true if any phrases match
  any(grepl(search_regex, phrases_in_d))
})
```

The result, as you expect, is a list of `false, false, true`.